# How to remove space between variable and string in php?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I made an upload site but there are some problems when I tried to make directory file path to move the file into it.

What is the difference between these two variables

```
$path = "data/users/".$user_id."/documents/ ".$_GET['id']."/".$new_name.".".$extn;
```

and

```
$path = "data/users/".$user_id."/documents/".$_GET['id']."/".$new_name.".".$extn;
```

what I needed is the below one, but I can't get it work. The above one gave me the space when it is inserted into mysql database. How can I get it work with the below one?

Comment: The answer: not writing a space if you don't want it there... if it's in a variable: `trim` might help, as will `str_replace(' ', '', $theVar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the space

```
$path = "data/users/".$user_id."/documents/ ".$_GET['id']."/".$new_name.".".$extn;
                                           ^HERE
```

Comment: I have done it with this option but it become another color and it didn't work.